# Spring-boot and spring-mvc compatibility

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

When I include spring-boot in my project, it has predefined versions of other spring components. eg: spring-boot 1.3.5 with spring-boot-starter-web automatically includes spring-mvc 4.2.6. if I want to use some features from webmvc 4.3, how can i know they are compatible? is there any compatibility matrix? or should i just treat it as a single release and never change versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring Boot will work the best for you if you don't try to resist defaults (of course change them only if necessary). You can include Spring 4.3 into Spring boot 1.3.x project, but I guess you will encounter various issues.

Version 1.4.0 will include Spring 4.3. [Spring Boot 1.4.0 is on Milestone 3 currently](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

BTW,
compatibility version for spring boot
 1.5x: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html

and for spring boot 2.0x:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html

Comment: Matrix location changed